# browserify-shim Sortable global not being recognized by react-sortable-mixin

Tags: reactjs, browserify-shim

I have a problem where react-sortable-mixin is not respecting the browserify-shim global:Sortable declaration in my package.json file thus causing the Sortable module to be packaged up in my bundle. I have run into a similar problem with other modules so it may very well be a config problem on my part. I have created a small test package that simply requires React and react-sortbable-mixin in order to demonstrate the problem:

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Just a test",
  "main": "index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^0.14.8",
    "sortablejs": "^1.4.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "browserify-shim": "^3.8.12"
  },
  "browserify": {
      "transform": [
          "browserify-shim"
      ]
  },
  "browserify-shim": {
    "react": "global:React",
    "sortablejs": "global:Sortable",
    "sortablejs/react-sortable-mixin": {
      "depends": "sortablejs:Sortable"
    }
  }
}
```

**index.js**

```
"use strict";
var React = require('react');
var SortableMixin = require('sortablejs/react-sortable-mixin');
```

**react-sortable-mixin.js** (Just the first part of the module...)

```
(function (factory) {
'use strict';

if (typeof module != 'undefined' && typeof module.exports != 'undefined') {
    module.exports = factory(require('./Sortable'));
}
else if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
    define(['./Sortable'], factory);
}
else {
    /* jshint sub:true */
    window['SortableMixin'] = factory(Sortable);
}
})(function (/** Sortable */Sortable) { ...
```

Here is the diagnostic output from browserify:

```
% BROWSERIFYSHIM_DIAGNOSTICS=1 browserify index.js -t browserify-shim -o bundle.js

{ file: '/home/jlafosse/test/index.js',
  info: 
   { package_json: '/home/jlafosse/test/package.json',
     packageDir: '/home/jlafosse/test',
     shim: undefined,
     exposeGlobals: { react: 'React', sortablejs: 'Sortable' },
     browser: undefined,
     'browserify-shim': 
      { react: 'global:React',
        sortablejs: 'global:Sortable',
        'sortablejs/react-sortable-mixin': { depends: 'sortablejs:Sortable' } },
     dependencies: { react: '^0.14.8', sortablejs: '^1.4.2' } },
  messages: 
   [ 'Resolved "sortablejs/react-sortable-mixin" found in package.json to "/home/jlafosse/test/sortablejs/react-sortable-mixin"',
     'Found depends "sortablejs" as an installed dependency of the package',
     { resolved: 
        { '/home/jlafosse/test/sortablejs/react-sortable-mixin': 
           { exports: null,
             depends: { sortablejs: 'Sortable' } } } } ] }

{ file: '/home/jlafosse/test/index.js',
  info: 
   { package_json: '/home/jlafosse/test/package.json',
     packageDir: '/home/jlafosse/test',
     resolvedPreviously: true,
     shim: undefined,
     exposeGlobals: { react: 'React', sortablejs: 'Sortable' },
     browser: undefined,
     'browserify-shim': 
      { react: 'global:React',
        sortablejs: 'global:Sortable',
        'sortablejs/react-sortable-mixin': { depends: 'sortablejs:Sortable' } },
     dependencies: { react: '^0.14.8', sortablejs: '^1.4.2' } },
  messages: [] }
```

I know the global shimming works because React is not included in the bundle... however as mentioned above, Sortable is being included. Also if I simply require('sortablejs') instead of the sortablejs/react-sortable-mixin in my index.js file, Sortable WILL NOT be included in the bundle as expected so my thought is that either my config is wrong or the module format for react-sortable-mixin does not respect browserify-shim.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Is your `Sortable` library actually available globally, i.e., with a script tag? It doesn't make sense that you'd use both `global:Sortable` and `./node_modules/sortablejs/Sortable.js:Sortable` in the same `package.json` file.

Comment: @YPCrumble - Yes I am including the Sortable CDN on the browser/client side.  I had initially tried doing:   "sortablejs/react-sortable-mixin": {"depends": "Sortable"}  as my understanding was that this would tell it to reference the global "Sortable" ,,, but this did not work either.

Comment: I'm assuming you specify the browserify shim `transform` directive? It's missing from your example `package.json`.

Comment: @YPCrumble - Yes it is in my original code but somehow got left out in the example. I updated the example to reflect this. I also updated the depends directive in the example.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible without modifying the contents of the Sortable library. Browserify Shim alters your `bundle.js` file to either include `window.PackageName` or the entire package, depending on the `browserify-shim` directive in your `package.json`.

In your situation, when you `require('sortablejs/react-sortable-mixin');` you're expecting Browserify Shim to alter the *contents* of `node_modules/sortablejs/react-sortable-mixin.js` such that `require('./Sortable')` becomes `window.Sortable` inside that file. The problem is that Browserify Shim doesn't alter the contents of the `node_modules` directory so this isn't possible.

There are a couple options:

1. Rather than loading Sortable via CDN, load it globally via your `bundle.js` script to ensure it is only loaded once. Your `index.js` would change to:

   ```
   window.Sortable = require('sortablejs');
   var SortableMixin = require('sortablejs/react-sortable-mixin');
   ```
2. Fork your own standalone file for `react-sortable-mixin.js` and bundle this directly in your bundle so that Browserify Shim can act on it.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. In regard to option #1, this still adds the Sortable library to the final bundle.js.... is this the intended behavior? In regard to option 2, I had considered that but I typically like to avoid forking maintained libs.

Comment: @Athan yes - the suggestion is really to say, put the library in your `bundle.js` file and load it that way **instead** of using the CDN. I'm assuming you needed the variable available globally as `Sortable` as if it had been loaded via CDN, which is why I included `window.Sortable`. If you don't need it available for other parts of your code as a variable on the `window` object you can change that line to simply `require('sortablejs');`.

Comment: Ok, thanks.  In regard to option 2, I did a quick test by copying the react-sortable-mixin.js from the node_modules and requiring the local copy, however I still get the same result where Sortable is being bundled up...

Comment: A update to SortableJS 1.10+ :

`window.Sortable = require('sortablejs').Sortable;`